# Using variable in table name

Tags: oracle

I am trying to use sysdate as a variable in a select on a table name.
the table name example is 'tableYYMMDD_test'
How do I use the variable like in the middle of the table name

Comment: which version of Oracle? what tool are you using? Generally, it is not possible to use variables in table_name, unless you're using dynamic sql. Besides, I'm not sure it's a good idea to have a table_per_day just to separate (partition) your data, better use just one partitioned table and let the database do the pruning.

Comment: Just to second comment by @gsalem - if you are naming your tables with business data (like the year of the data in the table) then your data model is seriously flawed.  Just. Don't. Do. It.